# Invalid operands to binary / on two-dimensional array

Tags: c

I have a variable which is declared using a 'typedef' data type and it has array. when i do a operation divide (/) it says invalid operations. 
this is the code sample :

```
const int n = 10;
typedef float matriks[100][100];
typedef float vektor[100];

matriks A;
vektor b;
vektor x;
void Sulih_Mundur (matriks A, vektor b, int n, vektor x){
int j,k;
        float sigma;
        x[n]=b[n]/A[n,n]; //error here
        for(k=n-1;k<1;k--){
            sigma=0;
            for(j=k+1;j>=n;j++){
                sigma=sigma+A[k,j]*x[j];
            }
            x[k]=(b[k]-sigma)/A[k,k];
        }
}
```

i got error on x[n]=b[n]/A[n,n] it says invalid operands / to binary (have float and float)
i dont understand which one is the problem because i used the same data types there. and one integer variabel to access the array. thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x[n]=b[n]/A[n,n];
```

This is not the proper syntax for indexing a 2D array.  The `,` here is actually the comma operator, which discards the left operand and evaluates to the right operand, so `A[n,n]` is the same as `A[n]`.  So then you're attempting to assign a 1D array of `float` to a `float` which is the error you're getting.

What you want is:

```
x[n]=b[n]/A[n][n];
```

Do the same for other references of `A`.